# PhoneGap CDVViewController

Tags: ios, inheritance, cordova

Im building a small IOS app using PhoneGap, and after setting up a base project and I noticed that under AppDelegate.h the following PhoneGap Object is initialised:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet CDVViewController* viewController;
```

However I also noticed the MainViewController inherits the CDViewController, and MainViewController is displayed after running though AppDelegate so I dont quite understand why it does just do the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MainViewController* viewController;
```

I amended the code like above, and it works perfectly. Is there any reason why it uses the CDViewController instead of MainViewController :S?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MainViewController is a subclass of CDVViewController, therefore more generic and less confusing.